# Make redirect in apache turns in 404

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to make a redirect with Apache. I have the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName sub.domain.com.br
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/folder
        ServerAlias www.sub.domain.com.br
        Options -Indexes

        ProxyRequests On
        ProxyPreserveHost On

        Redirect permanent https://www.sub.domain.com.br/tracking https://sub.domain.com.br:31311/
 ...
</VirtualHost *:80>
```

But when I'm getting

Not Found

The requested URL /abc was not found on this server.

when I try the url in browser.

How can I fix this?

Comment: First, check if your virtual host running? Is the RewriteEngine on?

Comment: Try `Redirect permanent /tracking https://sub.domain.com.br:31311/`. Remember, port 80 is for http, not https. Note: redirect permanent is not the same as reverse proxy.

Comment: thanks, it's working